# How to integrate the firebase 18.0.0 in android studio3.2

Tags: android, firebase

I am using firebase messaging for push notification. but after token not generated for specific users. this issue raised because of the onTokenRefresh method is depreciated in firebase messaging 11.2.0.

If I replace the OnnewToken function and make below changes in the manifest, sync issue shows in the project structure and the log shows **"failed to resolve the com.google.firebase: firebase.messaging18.0.0**". How to update the firebase in the android.

[image]

[image]

Build Gradle(Module: app)

dependencies
{
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'

}
Build.Gradle(Project: app)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
```

public class UrbanFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService implements OnBckgrdAsyncFinishListener {

```
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + token);
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend FirebaseMessagingService class and implement onNewToken method.

Comment: Already I extend this.kindly check my update code above. but firebase not update 18.0.0 version and show issue in the failure to resolve the com.google.firebase: firebase.messaging18.0.0 and above project structure issue.

Comment: try this implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'

Comment: add dependencies in gradle.app file module the second number file in gradle scripts

Comment: add dependencies in gradle.app file module the second number file in gradle scripts not understand what u ask? kindly check my question. already post the issue image

Comment: check google play services is installed in sdk tool manager.. if not then dowload it and sync

Comment: same error after installed the google play services

Answer (score 0):

You have two `build.gradle`:

`<PROJECT_ROOT>\app\build.gradle` is specific for app module.

`<PROJECT_ROOT>\build.gradle` is a "Top-level build file" where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

Inside the `build.gradle(app)` you need to add the firebase dependency:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
}
```

Update Google services:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
// ...
}
```

Comment: The following classpath `    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }` should be in the module build.gradle

Comment: update my code already i give this order only. but not working

Comment: Did you add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the bottom of the build.gradle(app)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204786/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-eve).

Comment: only support firebase 12.0.1  otherwise shows the error

Comment: Please enter the discussion